# How does jQuery hash domElements to use with data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

The sorcecode for jQuery is a little bit confusing to me, with a lot of global variables and cross-references.

I have several assumptions as to how `jQuery.data()` works: It creates a hashtable and hashes a domElement as a key, and sets the data as a value. I got to this conclusion since there is no changes to the dom, so somehow hashing the domElement is the only possible thing left.

Question 1: **How is it hashed?**

Question 2: **Is it possible to extend the hashing algorithm to work persistently with saved elements in the localStorage?**

Comment: My answer shows you the structure and how the data is saved in jQuery. Your question is about if it's possible but doesn't show any code or exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the `$.cache` variable. You can see it if you for example open your browser console and type it.

Here is an example

```js
$('div').data('tryme', 'okay');
$('p').data('try', 'okay');
   
$('div').append(JSON.stringify($.cache));
console.log($('div'), $('p'))
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<p></p>
```

## How it works

Each time you call `$(domElement)` jQuery will assign a key to it starting with *1*. You can think of it as an ID. As you can see in the result above each object with the data is assigned to a key.

When you call `$('div').data()`, jQuery will just get the key for that element and get the resulting data from the `$.cache` variable. You can check the keys doing something like

```js
$('div').each(function(){
  
  $(this).data(this.className, $(this).attr('data-class'));

});

$('div').each(function(){
  
  $('<div/>', {
    
    text: 'I am ' + this.className + ', my key is ' + this[$.expando] 
             + ' and my data is ' + JSON.stringify($.cache[this[$.expando]].data)
  
  }).appendTo('span');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ok1' data-class='test1'></div>
<div class='ok2' data-class='test2'></div>
<div class='ok3' data-class='test3'></div>
<div class='ok4' data-class='test4'></div>

<span>

</span>
```

With the result of this data you can simple save it in localStorage or do whatever you want.